# How do I configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to be a forward proxy for my private network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

im bought a new server machine and it came suprisingly with Windows Server 2008. I want to use this machine for several purposes: SQL Database, backup system, and a forward proxy for my private network. Can Windows Server 2008 handle this? The feature i need is mainly logging: I need to know what user accessed what net ressources. How would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general answer, it can handle this. For logging internet access, you would need to install and configure proxy software; it doesn't come with anything built-in. There are many options - there's ISA (now Forefront Threat Management Gateway 2010) from Microsoft, there's other free and commercial options.

Now, whether or not it's appropriate for a single server to be doing all of this is going to be specific to your situation - the client load for the proxy, expected utilization of the SQL server (and certainly RAM management - by default, SQL uses almost all of your RAM), etc. For all but the smallest of environments, I wouldn't run all of this on one server. But hey, maybe you want this for a very small environment.

As a side note :

> bought a new server machine and it came suprisingly with Windows Server 2008

This is troubling in at least 2 ways. You don't want to be surprised by what you buy; you want to know what you're paying for. Also, why would you be surprised by ordering a server and finding out that it comes with the latest server OS from Microsoft?

Comment: _This is troubling in at least 2 ways. You don't want to be surprised by what you buy; you want to know what you're paying for. Also, why would you be surprised by ordering a server and finding out that it comes with the latest server OS from Microsoft?_ Well. If you put it into context it isnt that troubling. I bought the cheapest available edition of the machine and was therefore surprised it came with an operating system. My last server machine came without.

Comment: Back to topic: Its mainly a proxy. The SQL Server would be hardly frequented. (Once every 2-3 days, mabye). So, is it still a problem? Lets talk about the proxy choices. Its a small private network (15 clients max). So a non-commercial alternative would suffice. I heard Apache can be configured as a proxy?

Comment: For SQL then, make sure you limit it's maximum memory. For proxy software, Apache would not be your best bet. If you want something free, Squid is used and liked by a lot of people.

Comment: Then I will try squid.